# JavaScript Radio Buttons and event handling

Tags: javascript, html, forms, events

I am trying to set-up an interactive booklet with questions.

I have set-up an example question in a table which has a radio button to select the correct answer.

However when I run the script the alert box ( test ) I have set-up runs straight away and the script is null.

The **exact error**:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of 
nullinteractive.js:34 mainQuestionOneinteractive.js:38 
(anonymous function)
```

**My code**:

HTML

```
    <section class="question-one">
        <h4>Question 1</h4>
        <p>
            Which <stong>one</stong> of the following statements best describes the function of bookkeeping?
        </p>
        <table border="1">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        A form of internal accounting providing finanical information at a time and in a format which makes it useable by management for the purpose of planning and controlling a business
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="radio" name="question-one" id="question-one"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                    <td>
                        The mechanistic system of processing and recording the day-to-day financial transactions of a business
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="radio" name="question-one" id="question-two"  />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                </tr>
                    <td>
                        The mechanistic system of processing and recording the day-to-day financial transactions of a business
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="radio" name="question-one" id="question-three" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </section>
```

JavaScript

```
/*--------------------------------------------
QUESTION ONE - LOGIC
----------------------------------------------*/
function mainQuestionOne() {

    var questionOne;
    var questionTwo;
    var questionThree;

    questionOne = document.getElementById('question-one');
    questionTwo = document.getElementById('question-two');
    questionThree = document.getElementById('question-three');

    questionOne.onclick = alert('test');
    questionTwo.onclick = alert('test2');
    questionThree.onclick = alert('test3');
}
mainQuestionOne();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap your `alert()` with `function() {...}`.

```
function mainQuestionOne() {
    var questionOne = document.getElementById('question-one');
    questionOne.onclick = function() { alert('test'); }
}
mainQuestionOne();
```

[JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/eL3nvhro/)

Comment: I have just done what you have said and no luck. I get the same error again. Any more ideas? thank you as well

Comment: Added a Fiddle link for your reference, hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

Question 1

Which
            one
            of the following statements best describes the function of bookkeeping?

A form of internal accounting providing finanical information at a time and in a format which makes it useable by management for the purpose of planning and controlling a business
                    
                    
                        
                    
                
                
                    The mechanistic system of processing and recording the day-to-day financial transactions of a business
                    
                    
                        
                    
                
                
                    The mechanistic system of processing and recording the day-to-day financial transactions of a business

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function que1() {
        alert('test1');
    }
    function que2() {
        alert('test2');
    }
    function que3() {
        alert('test3');
    }

</script>
```

call function 'onclick' event of radio button